# Areas not displaying in MVC 4 using MvcExtensions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, autofac, mvcextensions

I am using `ASP.NET MVC 4 RC` and the latest version of `MvcExtensions` and `MvcExtensions.Autofac`.

I don't know if MVC 4 works differently to MVC 3, but my areas aren't displaying at all when using it with MvcExtensions.  The code below is how I used it in my MVC 3 application.  I have just copied and pasted it into my MVC 4 app.  If I use the default Global.asax.cs file that came with the MVC 4 application then my areas display properly.  Must this be done differently?

I replaced the Global.asax.cs file to look like this:

```
public class MvcApplication : AutofacMvcApplication
{
     public MvcApplication()
     {
          Bootstrapper.BootstrapperTasks
               .Include<RegisterAreas>()
               .Include<RegisterControllers>()
               .Include<RegisterRoutesBootstrapper>()
               .Include<AutoMapperBootstrapper>()
               .Include<FluentValidationBootstrapper>();
     }

     protected override void OnStart()
     {
          FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

          base.OnStart();
     }
}
```

`RegisterRoutesBootstrapper`, `AutoMapperBootstrapper` and `FluentValidationBootstrapper` are my custom bootstrapper classes.

Answer (score 1):

I've just created a test Mvc4 app with MvcExtensions (v2.5.0) and with a custom area. Everything works fine for me.

Please make sure that you have bindingRedirects in your root web.config file:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Without these binding redirects areas will not work.